# Java Priority Queue Issue

Tags: java, queue

Issue: I've got a priority queue to process actions. When I instantiate the actions and then add them to the queue it works, however when I instantiate them directly as I add them to the queue it no longer retains the priority.

**This works** - Executes by priority

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Action<Void> low = new LowAction();
    final Action<Void> med = new MedAction();
    final Action<Integer> high = new HighAction();
    final Action<Boolean> walk = new WalkAction();

    final ActionScheduler scheduler = new ActionScheduler(1,10);

    scheduler.queue(high);
    scheduler.queue(walk);
    scheduler.queue(low);
    scheduler.queue(med);

}
```

**This does not work** - Executes in the order I called them

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    final ActionScheduler scheduler = new ActionScheduler(1,10);

    scheduler.queue(new HighAction());
    scheduler.queue(new WalkAction());
    scheduler.queue(new LowAction());
    scheduler.queue(new MedAction());

}
```

ActionScheduler class

```
public class ActionScheduler {

private ExecutorService priorityJobPoolExecutor;
private ExecutorService priorityJobScheduler
        = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
private PriorityBlockingQueue<Action<?>> priorityQueue;
private Future<?> result;

public ActionScheduler(Integer poolSize, Integer queueSize) {
    priorityJobPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
    priorityQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(queueSize);
    priorityJobScheduler.submit(() -> {
        while (true) {
            try {
                result = priorityJobPoolExecutor.submit(priorityQueue.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}

public void schedule(Action<?> action) {
    priorityQueue.offer(action);
}

public <T> Future<T> queue(Action<?> action) {
    this.schedule(action);
    return (Future<T>) result;
}
```

}

**This also works correctly**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Action<Void> low = new LowAction();
    final Action<Void> med = new MedAction();
    final Action<Integer> high = new HighAction();
    final Action<Boolean> walk = new WalkAction();

    final ActionScheduler scheduler = new ActionScheduler(1,10);

    scheduler.queue(new HighAction());
    scheduler.queue(new WalkAction());
    scheduler.queue(new LowAction());
    scheduler.queue(new MedAction());

}
```

If anyone could offer any insight on why this is happening and how I can get it to execute by priority in both examples posted it would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Action Class

```
    public abstract class Action<T> implements Callable<T>, Comparable<Action<?>> {

    private final ActionContext context;

    public Action(ActionContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Action action) {
        if (action.getContext().getPriority() == this.getContext().getPriority()) {
            return 0;
        } else if (this.getContext().getPriority().ordinal() > action.getContext().getPriority().ordinal()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }

    }

    public ActionContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

LowAction class

```
   public class LowAction extends Action<Void> {
    public LowAction() {
        super(new ActionContext("low", Priority.LOW, true, false));
    }


    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("LOW");
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I assume that you're having timing issues with the threading, the priority queue works fine.

Comment: What is `Action` and those `XxxAction`?

Comment: Have you tried to change your order in the first case by replacing low with the medium ?

Comment: I've added the Action and LowAction classes I am still not sure why this issue is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

There is one difference which I can see in the first approach you are binding your object with an actual type like `final Action<**Void**> low = new LowAction();` on the other hand `new LowAction()` will be treat as a raw creation.
The internal working of the PriorityQueue is based on the Binary Heap.The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to the natural ordering, or by a comparator provided at construction time of the queue, depending on which constructor is used.